# Durandaljs pushState changed the behavior on 1 page

Tags: durandal, durandal-2.0, durandal-navigation

I'm using durandal pushState for SEO. All pages working correct but one. When I load this page - it loads(activates) 2 times instead of 1. When I make 'pushState:false' - this page works correct. What can be the problem of this page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not now why, but it was a problem just in this: "router: router,"
place, when I removed it - page loaded correctly...